# Is it possible to use just one Qt module, just like a 3rd party dll?

Tags: database, qt, qtsql

I'd been looking for a DB access library for C++ which will run under Windows. I tried

- SOCI: does not compile
- SQLAPI++: not free

Next option was to use Qt's DB access module, QtSql.

Is it possible only to use QtSql without importing or linking any other Qt stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can compile against only a part of the Qt Dlls. But I guess in all cases you have to build against QtCore too.
So your .pro file should have

```
qt += core sql
```

Comment: Hi, i don't have a pro file, i use vs2005. Can i simply add lib files for core and sql, and then i'm done?
note: project is not a qt project, in short i just wanna use a couple of qt classes.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Qt dll are independent (except with the core)

Comment: Be very careful with QtSql since Sql drivers are plugins, they need a proper Qt plugin file structure to be loaded (they may need a QApplication too depending the way you build it)